# How to select and copy from rich text in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app (still on 0.59.9), and I have some users on iOS and others on Android.

Some users (on our website, not on our mobile app) can generate rich text (e.g., it includes bold, links, and bullet points) that other users (on our mobile app) can view.  When someone is viewing this text, they should be able to select it and copy it, similar to what you would do in a webpage (e.g., long tap and then select a custom subset of the text to copy).

The `selectable` prop on a `Text` component seems to allow selection and copying, but it seems like that only works for the whole component.  The user can't customize what gets selected, at least on iOS.

Some folks online recommend using a `TextInput`, but it seems like you can't nest elements inside the `TextInput`, which would mean I couldn't display rich text to the user.  It's okay if it gets copied as plain text, but it needs to be displayed as rich text.

Also, it's fine if it doesn't use the native copy dialog -- I can make a custom component and use `Clipboard` to do the copying -- but I still haven't figured out how to let the user select the text in the first place.

So, what is the best practice for the general case of selecting and copying text in React Native?

Thanks!